# jQuery Animate Div Resize Backwards

Tags: jquery

I've got an empty div that I want to resize using jQuery, here is the code i'm using so far:

```
$('#container').animate({ height: '-=350px'}, 1000);
```

It works fine but I need it to animate from top to bottom, at the moment the bottom of the div moves up the page, but I need the top of the div to move down the page, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `$('#container').animate({ height: '-=350px', top: '+=350px'}, 1000);`

Comment: hmf - jQuery always surprises me how simply everything is, stick in an answer so i can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery animate, it's pretty slick.

Just add the `top` property to the animation object:

```
$('#container').animate({ height: '-=350px', top: '+=350px'}, 1000);
```

This will cause the top of the div to go down at the same speed as the height goes up, giving the illusion that it's "closing" from the top, rather than from the bottom.